# Как сделать чтобы функция открыла окно, дождалась ввода, закрыла окно и вернула введенное

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
def run(quest, typeOf='Any'):
    tkinp = Tk()
    tkinp.geometry('200x100')
    tkinp['bg'] = 'cyan'
    tkinp.resizable(0, 0)
    tkinp.title('Enter')

    var = StringVar(tkinp)
    entryIn = Entry(tkinp, textvariable=var)
    entryIn.place(x=10, y=70, width=180)

    Label(tkinp, text=f'{quest}:', bg='cyan').place(x=10, y=40)
    Label(tkinp, text=f'Тип: {typeOf}', bg='cyan').place(x=10, y=20)

    def end(event):
        varGet = var.get()
        return varGet

    tkinp.bind('<Return>', end)
    
    tkinp.mainloop()

print(run('Вопрос'))
```

**Как сделать, чтобы эта функция вернула что-то**, в данном случае для принта. Ничего не возвращается из-за того, что у tkinter запущено `mainloop`, поэтому `return` не работает (мне кажется так).

Comment: какая функция должна что-то вернуть (кстати, что именно?) и куда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` во внутренней функции не делает выход из внешней функции. Тут нужно вручную убить окно, а во внешней функции ждать, пока окно существует с помощью метода `.wait_window()`, потом из внешней функции вернуть результат (обычно это используется с дочерними окнами типа `Toplevel`, но в главным окном тоже сработает):

```
from tkinter import *


def run(quest, typeOf='Any'):
    ...

    result = None
    def end(event):
        nonlocal result
        result = var.get()  # Записываем результат в переменную result внешней функции
        tkinp.destroy()  # Уничтожаем окно

    tkinp.bind('<Return>', end)
    tkinp.wait_window()  # Ждем уничтожения окна
    return result  # Возвращаем результат


print(run('Вопрос'))
```

На самом деле для главного окна (не `Toplevel`) можно было бы использовать и `mainloop()` вместо `wait_window()` (`mainloop()` тоже прекратит работу после уничтожения окна, и выполнится код, который идет в функции ниже, например тот же `return`), но вариант с `wait_window()` более универсальный.

Comment: Спасибо, я добавил проверку, чтобы return был только если result is not none, и всё отлично работает!

Comment: @Koteyka смотря как и куда добавили. У вас должно что-то возвращаться, если окно просто закрыли, по идее это должно быть None. Тогда нужно в вызывающем коде проверять, что вернулось не None, а в самой функции ничего дополнительно проверять не нужно.